# What forbids the existence of a $\lambda (A^\mu A_\mu)^2$ term in the Stueckelberg action?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, higgs

In QFT, the Stueckelberg "trick" is often used to show how one can write a fully gauge invariant Lagrangian out of one that is not. For example, if we have

$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} + m^2 A^\mu A_\mu$,

the gauge invariance becomes apparent when we rewrite the massive gauge boson in terms of a new vector field and a scalar field $\phi$: $A^\mu \rightarrow A^\mu + \frac{1}{m}\partial_\mu \phi$. Then, the Lagrangian is then invariant under $\delta \phi = -m \Lambda(x)$ and $\delta A_\mu = \partial_\mu \Lambda(x)$.

My question is this: typically, we do not ever see terms present in the above Lagrangian like $\lambda (A^\mu A_\mu)^2$. Moreover, it seems like we can always continue to add terms like $(A^\mu A_\mu)^4/m^2$, which clearly seems like a problem. If we regard the Stueckelberg theory as one in which the Higgs has been integrated out and we are only left with the massless Goldstone bosons $\phi$, terms like $\lambda (A^\mu A_\mu)^2$ should become very relevant at high energies by dimensional analysis. I would love some clarification on why they are never present in the Lagrangian.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the Stueckelberg-Lagrangian is written down for a massive *photon*, a vector boson of the $U(1)$ gauge group. As photons are not self-interacting, interaction terms (i.e. $A^3$ or higher order) are not present.

The idea is that renormalizability can be restored in a theory with broken gauge invariance. The Stueckelberg formalism serves as a tool to make the Proca-Lagrangian gauge invariant by introducing an additional scalar field. When calculating perturbation series, its mass is sent to infinity in order to keep this field from influencing the physical results.

Comment: Thanks; how would this argument generalize to the non-Abelian case?

Comment: You can find a paper on precisely this question here: http://ptp.oxfordjournals.org/content/37/2/452

Comment: Note: the renormalizability is only restored in the abelian case with this trick. In the non-abelian case you have a nonlinear sigma model, which has a higher cut off, but its still non-renormalizable.

Answer (score 0):

A similar term appears, e.g., in scalar electrodynamics (Klein-Gordon-Maxwell electrodynamics) as follows. As Schroedinger noted (please see the reference in my article in Int'l J. of Quantum Information - http://akhmeteli.org/akh-prepr-ws-ijqi2.pdf ), the scalar matter field in scalar electrodynamics can be made real by a gauge transform. The resulting equations of motions can be obtained from a Lagrangian containing a term that is similar to the term that you discuss (please see Eq. 14 and the reference in my above-mentioned article).