# Stueckelberg mechanism for interacting QFTs

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

The Stueckelberg mechanism or "trick" (see e.g. Section 4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3735) is basically a method to take the massless limit of massive gauge theories in a smooth way, namely preserving the number of degrees of freedom. In its perhaps simplest example, one can show that the Proca theory for a massive spin 1 (whose action is schematically $-F^2 -m^2 A^2$) in the massless limit becomes the theory of a free photon plus the theory of a free massless scalar, and the two are completely decoupled.

My question is the following: does this hold when the massive theory is interacting? Say that beyond the kinetic and mass term for the massive vector, in the Lagrangian I also have all possible interactions (for simplicity let's restrict ourself to the terms that contribute to the $2\to2$ scattering, so with four fields): $(A^2)^2$, $\partial^2 A^4$, etc. Again, I'm being schematic with the indices. I would like to understand if the massless limit of this theory is the sum of two Lagrangians, one for the interacting photon and one for the interacting massless scalar:
$$
\mathcal{L}^{int}_{A(m)} \quad \overset{m\to 0}{\longrightarrow} \quad \mathcal{L}^{int}_{A} + \mathcal{L}^{int}_{\phi}.
$$
To prove this, one would need to prove that it's possible to get rid of the interactions between the photon and the scalars $\mathcal{L}^{int}_{A,\phi}$ using gauge transformations and a clever gauge choice. Is there a general argument, or do I need to work order by order in the interaction terms of the original massive Lagrangian?

Comment: Hi Rubilax96. Are you assuming that the gauge theory is abelian?

Comment: Let's say yes. I've seen this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78885/, but I have in mind a case in which interactions exist because I'm considering some effective field theory regime and I don't care about renormalizability. So $A^4$ and higher order terms do matter,

Comment: So specifically what I call $\mathcal{L}^{int}_A$ would be like the Euler-Heisenberg Lagrangian.